# javascript check setTimeout is running

Tags: javascript, settimeout

```
function TimerSystem() {
    this.timer = null;

    this.addTimer = function(timer, delay) {
        this.timer = timer;

        setTimeout(function() {
            timerSystem.timer = null;
        }, delay);
    };
}
var timerSystem = new TimerSystem();


timerSystem.addTimer(setTimeout(function() {
            //do something...
        }, 1000), 1000);
```

It is working in my source.
Let me know this way is right? 
I think this is not intelligent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember the timeoutId, and set it to null when the timer func runed, like this:

```
function schedule(func, millsecs) {

    var timeId = setTimeout(function() {

        //the function runed, clear this timeId
        timeId = null;

        func();

    }, millsecs);

    return {

        isrunning : function() {

            return timeId != null;
        }
    };
}

var sinfo = schedule(function() {

    console.log('done');

}, 500);

console.log('just now', sinfo.isrunning());
```

http://jsfiddle.net/rooseve/AVna6/1/

Besides, why you need to "check setTimeout is running"?

Comment: I want to block user input while timer is running.
Thankyou! :)